# Filtering dataframe in pandas based on a list of strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, indexing, pandas-groupby

I have started exploring pandas recently, I am trying to import a list of fruits from sector.py and use it as a filter to produce a table of items where only fruits within the list are displayed. I am not getting the output desired is there something wrong with my codes?

Within sector.py

```
Fruits=['Apple','Orange','Pineapples']
```

Within calculator.py

```
import sector
import pandas as pd

pdmart = pd.read_csv('supermarket.csv')
pdextract = pdmart.groupby('item')['price'].sum()

Fruits = pdextract[pdextract.isin(sector.Fruits)]
print Fruits
```

Current output:

```
Series([], Name: price, dtype: float64)
```

Desired output:

```
Item         Price
Apple        12.0
Orange       7.0
Pineapples   15.0
```

Comment: just filter before the groupby, that should do it

Comment: or reindex with the list after the groupby, which will ensure you display NaN for groups you are missing completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying `isin` on a `GroupBy` object doesn't make sense. You can use Boolean indexing on the *index* of your `GroupBy` object:

```
Fruits = pdextract[pdextract.index.isin(sector.Fruits)]
```

You can also filter on a series *before* your `GroupBy` operation:

```
pdextract = pdmart.loc[pdmart['item'].isin(sector.Fruits)]\
                  .groupby('item')['price'].sum()
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply, could you explain a little more on why I can't group them before apply isin on the groupings?

Comment: @SamT, You can. My first solution is after the `GroupBy`. Notice `pdextract` is the `GroupBy` object as in your question.

Comment: cool! thank you! also, if i were to sum up the values of all the fruits, could I do a .sum() again on the variable pdextract?

Meaning to say: 
Fruits 34.0

Apologies if i am vague, this is my first language..

Comment: @SamT, Sure, give it a go. But if you have a new question, you should ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). This isn't a forum.

Comment: @jpp this is because after doing pdextract = pdmart.groupby('item')['price'].sum() the groupby column becomes the default index column right?

Comment: @ubuntu_noob, There is, `groupby('item', as_index=False)` or `groupby('item')['price'].sum().reset_index()`. But indexing is generally a good idea for efficiency / structure.